# Sliding up div overlaps outer div?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to slideup all other sub-menu div and fadein current sub-menu but while sliding up  other sub-menu div overlaps outer div.

Here is code : [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n5eZQ/)

```
     $(document).ready(function(e){
             $(".item").click(function(){                                 
                $(this).nextAll().children('div').stop().slideUp();
                $(this).prevAll().children('div').stop().slideUp();
                $(this).children('div').fadeIn(1000);
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply do this : [See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankittyagi/n5eZQ/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $(".item").click(function(){                                 
        $(this).nextAll().children('div').stop().slideUp();
        $(this).prevAll().children('div').stop().slideUp();
        $(this).children('div').slideDown();
    });
});
```

Comment: i want to do sliding effect like this http://imagery.gettyimages.com/getty_images_keyword_guide/usa/?isource=USA_SearchTips_keywords    goto PEOPLE category therefor i used fadein

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
overflow:hidden;
```

to     #products div. See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5eZQ/2/)

```
#products {
            margin: 10px;
            float: left;  
            overflow:hidden;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            height: 490px;
            box-shadow: 0px 1px 7px 2px #050505;
            width: 300px;
            background:gray;

        }
```